# iPython: Kill a for-loop with try/except in it?

Tags: python, ipython

I know I should avoid getting into these situations, but I like to use iPython and keep variables around while I experiment.  I paste sections of code in from Spyder and let them run, then examine variables, etc.  Now, I have a section of code like this:

```
for a in range(bignum):
  try:
    <something>
  except:
    print('Badness')
```

I kick it off and realize that I have a mistake in there, but now I can't stop it with ctrl-C because the try/except just prints the message and moves on.  Is there a way to stop the loop without throwing away my session?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use a 'catch-all' `except` clause without specific exceptions. Just add the relevant exceptions to it, and your `KeyboardInterrupt` won't be caught.

Comment: Yes, I've learned that lesson, but I was curious if there was any way out of this once I already made the mistake.

Comment: So to be clear: you've currently got a session running that you can't stop with Ctrl+C, and you want to know if there's any way you can salvage the session without changing the code?

Comment: It's a mistake I have made more than once.  I'm not currently suffering from it, but I wanted to know the answer to the question (can the session be salvaged?).  I'm aware of the option to specifically catch KeyboardInterrupt, but in the heat of testing ideas, I don't always do it, foolishly not expecting an issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `break` inside the `except` clause to get yourself out of the loop. Alternatively, you can move the for loop *inside* the try/except block. If you want to do one thing for `KeyboardInterrupt` (ctrl+c) and another thing for *any other exception*, you can catch either separately.

```py
for a in range(big_num):
  try:
    pass # Do your thing
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("You pressed ctrl c...")
    break
  except Exception as e: # Any other exception
    print(str(e)) # Displays the exception without raising it
    break
```

or

```py
try:
  for a in range(big_num):
    pass # Do your thing
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("You pressed ctrl c...")
except Exception as e:
  print(str(e))
```

Comment: The first of these works great for my application, if I remember to do it.  I'd still be interested to know if there is any recourse once the more basic loop is off and running.